# Replace text quickly in very large file

Tags: sed, replace, large-files

I have 25GB text file that needs a string replaced on only a few lines. I can use `sed` successfully but it takes a really long time to run.

```
sed -i 's|old text|new text|g' gigantic_file.sql
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: Do you know the line numbers where the text to replace is?  If not your only option for speeding it up is to get a faster computer.  The fact that you have a large amount of data means it will take a large amount of time to search through it.

Comment: I can grep for the line numbers pretty quickly, so yes.

Comment: You can also use multiple CPU cores to speed it up - http://www.rankfocus.com/use-cpu-cores-linux-commands/

Comment: Don't use sed for large files.  Take a look at [vi or vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files) instead.

Answer (score 50):

You can try:

```
sed -i '/old text/ s//new text/g' gigantic_file.sql
```

From this [ref](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt):

> OPTIMIZING FOR SPEED: If execution speed needs to be increased (due to
>   large input files or slow processors or hard disks), substitution will
>   be executed more quickly if the "find" expression is specified before
>   giving the "s/.../.../" instruction.

Here is a comparison over a 10G file. Before:

```
$ time sed -i 's/original/ketan/g' wiki10gb
real    5m14.823s
user    1m42.732s
sys     1m51.123s
```

After:

```
$ time sed -i '/ketan/ s//original/g' wiki10gb
real    4m33.141s
user    1m20.940s
sys     1m44.451s
```

Comment: The last `sed` is misspelled. I edited this post yesterday to fix the last `sed` command which should be `time sed -i '/original/ s//ketan/g' wiki10gb` and not `time sed -i '/ketan/ s//original/g' wiki10gb`. I'm reverting my edit today because 1. the times no longer match the command and 2. I have done the same test with GNU sed on a 3+ GB file and I do not observe any difference between the two `sed` alternatives. I suspect that the difference in times is due to the misspelling.

Comment: @xhienne I am not sure what you mean by misspelling. In the first run, I am substituting the word 'original' with 'ketan' and in the second one I am substituting term 'ketan' with the term 'original' resulting in equal number of substitutions in either case.

Comment: I was applying a "fix" reported by a new user with not enough reputation. Now I understand what you did. However, if you want to prove that one syntax is better than one another, you have to do the exact same operation which is not the case here (CPU-wise, looking for a 5-char string is not the same as looking for a 7-char string). Moreover, this kind of test on a 10GB file is heavily dependent on your machine load (CPU, disk). I saw a lot of fluctuations in the `time` results personally, but all in all, there was no difference in time.

Comment: I believe this is related -- see the accepted answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145270/how-to-replace-an-entire-line-in-a-text-file-by-line-number >> sed streams the entire file, but as noted in this answer, specifying the line number (if known) helps: in my case, a ~2-fold increase in execution speed (GNU sed 4.5). You can grep -n or ripgrep (rg) to find line numbers, based on pattern searches.  In effect, specifying the line number is like having a search result on that file, per the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "No" - your limiting factor on this sort of operation is disk IO. There is no way to stream 25GB of a disk any faster. You might get a minor improvement if you don't inplace edit, and you write the result of the `sed` to a separate drive (if you have one available) - because that way you can be reading from one, whilst writing to another and there's slightly less contention as a result.

You *might* be able to speed it up a bit by not using the regex engine for each line - so for example using perl (I'm pretty sure you can do this with `sed` but I don't know the syntax) - this will start from line 10,000 onwards.

```
perl -pe '$. > 10_000 && s/old_text/new_text/g'
```

And if there's any sort of complications in the RE (metacharacters) then minimising those will *slightly* improve the efficiency of the regex engine.

Comment: In sed that would be `sed -i '10000,$ s/old_text/new_text/g'`

Comment: Lovely. I don't know how `sed` compares - I assume marginally faster, but not much because of the file size.

Comment: I'd assume perl is faster than sed, but sed is somewhat less cryptic, or rather requires less of an initial learning curve.

Comment: See, now I'd have said the opposite - you can (almost) write `sed` in `perl`, but the latter also lets you write more verbose scripts too.

Answer (score 0):

If the new and old texts are the same length, you can seek into the file and write only the changed bytes, instead of copying the whole file.  Otherwise you are trapped into moving lots of data.

Note: this is tricky and involves​ writing custom code.

See the man page for fseek if you're working in C or C++, or your favored language wrappers for the seek and write system calls.

If you insist on using the command line only, and you can get the byte offsets of the text, you can write the replacement text in place with carefully written "dd" commands.